# Finding the age of a specific key on memcache

Tags: memcached

Is there a quick way of discovering the age of a specific key on memcache?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Memcached does not keep information on when keys are created so it is not possible to do this unless you have some sort of client side logic. If this is important to you then you can simply add the creation time as a prefix to the actual value of the key (value = time + data). Then when you get the data from memcached you can split the value into the corresponding pieces of data.

Comment: I quite like that idea of splitting of the data.

Answer (score 2):

OP, do you refer to knowing the age of a cache entry? You can store the timestamp of the latest update along with the actual value:

```
from datetime import datetime

def put_value(key, value):
    timestamp = datetime.utcnow()
    entry = (timestamp, value)
    memcache.add(key, entry)


def get_value(key):
    entry = memcache.get(key)

    if not value:
        return None

    _, value = entry
    return value


def get_age(key):
    entry = memcache.get(key)

    if not value:
        return None

    timestamp, _ = entry
    age = datetime.utcnow() - timestamp
    return age
```